# OpenGL-ES iOS DrawText on screen drops FPS dramastically

Tags: ios, performance, text, opengl-es, drawing

Our team has developed an OpenGL application which draws different polygons on the screen. Additionally we want to create about 1000 different strings to print on the screen. If we do this with the Texture2D class the FPS drops down under 3.

I've already tested Bitmap fonts, which doesn't improve the performance.

Which is the best way in OpenGL iOS to draw a lot of text without loss of performance and without losing quality (text should be scalable)?

Answer (score 0):

Allocating 1000 textures takes up a huge amount of memory and will slow down your app, especially if they are at a high enough resolution for readable text. You should generate these textures **as they are needed** and free them once they are no longer being displayed. Make sure that you aren't generating and freeing textures each frame, but only as needed.

If you are drawing all 1000 strings in the same scene, you should combine as many as you can into like textures. This will allow you to leverage Cocos2D's TrueType rendering system to keep text high-quality. On the other hand if this is not an option and all 1000 strings need to be distinct from each other, consider building a font rendering system that renders each character as a glyph image. This will reduce the number of textures used from 1000 to about 100 to represent all standard English characters and punctuation. I had to do something similar for a video game with lots of dynamic text in an OpenGL environment, and got good performance out of it. However, I do not recommend it unless it's absolutely necessary since it limits your text to only the glyphs you define and you have to program the formatting yourself.

Comment: I've implemented that only the textures, available to the screen get created and free them after used. I think my problem is, as you described, that I draw and create them on each new rendering process, which is the bottleneck. Do you have any idea how I can avoid it? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Yes, create the textures for all glyphs that you plan to use (upper and lower case, numerals, punctuation, etc.) and store these textures in a custom text-handling class. Then add a member function to the class that takes a string and a modelview matrix as an argument. The function should look up the textures for each glyph in the string and draw them starting at the modelview, translating the modelview by the width of each glyph after drawing. This will reduce memory usage from 1000 largeish textures to about 100 small ones.

Comment: If you don't want to go about making a font system like this and can spare the memory, I'd just create all the textures of the strings at startup and then call them up as needed, only deleting them when the program shuts down. In fact, I'd do this first and only consider doing my above comment if you don't like the performance this gives you.